# Загругрузка изображений под разные устройства

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

Как в storyboard в `UIImageView` загрузить различные разрешение картинок под разные девайсы (интересует 2x для основновных устройств и 3x для устройств формата 6+ и 7+)

Comment: а зачем это в строиборд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сториборд ничего загружать не надо. просто подключить к проекту соответствующие изображения.

Т.е. Если в сториборде указана картинка '1.png', то система сама при запуске на retina будет искать '1@2x.png' и подставит ее. И, соответственно, '1@3x.png' для iPhone 6 plus

Comment: Спасибо за помощ!